# Hide TieredMenu after click item

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, menu

I have a problem with a TieredMenu event.

I want to close de menu after click an item but I can't do it.

Here is the code of the page

```
    <p:column id="columnaMenu" width="4%" style="align:center" exportable="false">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText   value="Acciones" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:commandButton id="dynaButton" type="button" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-acciones" styleClass="acciones" ajax="false"/>
        <p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="dynaButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" style="width:270px" id="menuAcciones" widgetVar="wvAcciones">
            <p:menuitem value="#{ptf['btn.verSecuenciaFirmas']}" rendered="#{solicitud.numDocumentos==1}" action="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.secuenciaFirmas(solicitud,'N')}" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>
        </p:tieredMenu>                             
    </p:column>
```

The menu is on a column of datatable and I show a popUp after click item (method secuenciaFirmas of the bean)

What can I do?

Comment: It 'just works' in the showcase... https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tieredMenu.xhtml

Comment: but in my example don't works...

Comment: Your 'example' is a 'snippet'. Create a [mcve]... Try e.g. if it starts working outside a datatable. Or try with the latest PF (6.0/6.1RC2 at time of writing) instead of an undefined version

Comment: I do face this issue, it works fine in showcase ONLY